# google map geocoding api webservice

Tags: google-maps

I am calling a Google Geocoding Maps API and somehow it's throwing me the following error:

The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required

I couldn't find any documentation on Google website on whether I need to have a Google Maps Key or need to create an account?

I am calling this webservice: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding this to your solution?

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
   <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://webproxy:80" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

or try the following

```
string url = “Valid URL”;
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
NetworkCredential netcredit = new NetworkCredential(“user1″, “pass”, “domain”);
req.Credentials = netcredit;
System.Net.WebProxy pry = new WebProxy(“proxyServer”,true);
pry.Credentials = netcredit;
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = pry;
req.Method = “HEAD”; //Does not work if this line is not used
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
NetworkCredential netcredit = new NetworkCredential(“user1″, “pass”, “domain”);
req.Credentials = netcredit;
System.Net.WebProxy pry = new WebProxy(“proxyServer”,true);
pry.Credentials = netcredit;
req.Proxy = pry;
req.Method = “HEAD”; //Does not work if this line is not used
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

People have the solution in this forum

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-api/0js1jr4kqJw

Comment: thanks. the above code works me through the line that was throwing me an error before but my Google web service is still not working. It's returning me an object but now throws me this error:  "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."

Comment: I presume it is something wrong with the proxy.Do I need to configure the proxy to map the maps.googleapis.com domain?